# Getting WP Tinymce's Content

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to write a Wordpress plugin. I will get counts words which in WP's  Tinymce editor.
Basically, it's a word counter which counting long of your post and giving you this message in a meta box

> Your post has 450 words

My just problem is getting words from Tinymce via javascript. This isn't working :

```
document.getElementById('content')
```

Tinymce's content's id is *content* . But this code returning NULL. I couldn't find valid id name for Tinymce.

In shortly, other all codes are ready, just i can't get words from Wordpress' WYSIWYG editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

or

```
tinymce.editors.content.getContent();
```

Where "content" is the id of your textarea.

Similarly, if you wanted to get just the selected (highlighted) text in the TinyMCE text area you would do:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
```

The full API is here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Editor

TinyMCE also offers a lot of events you can bind to, particularly in your case the [keyup](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp), [keydown](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyDown), and [keypressed](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyPress) events.

Be sure to call this stuff only after TinyMCE has loaded on the page.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I can't believe it was so simple.

Comment: As savitas mentioned in his answer below, these solutions won't work for all custom editors - especially if you have hyphens in the ID. Although it's not a tinymce issue, just the way javascript works, it might give you some trouble. Savitas' answer is to use "editors" as an array instead: `tinymce.editors['content_id'].getContent();`

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes wordpress hasn't yet registered a given tinymce editor. Also, wordpress has js functions removep() and autop() which remove and add various entities, like <p> that tinymce.getContent() likes to add. Instead try using `wp.editor.getContent('content')`. There's not much documentation on it, but I've found it returns exactly what will get stored in the database.

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer did work for me but for multiple editors on one page I have to access it via editor id, so below

```
tinymce.editors['content_id'].getContent();
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I remember that tiny MCE loads content dynamically from ajax, so maybe your  `document.getElementById('content')` try to get that element too early.

I think you have 2 ways to solve this problem:

1) wait for the ajax event completition, with an event listener, and after that get the element and its text.

2) use tinyMce function to get the content of a text area. Here you may find some useful tips:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/How-to_load/save_with_Ajax_in_TinyMCE

Comment: Thank you Manuel,now i'll try it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. The text below the editor will be updated whether the keyup occured in Visual or HTML mode.

[image: WP tinyMCE onKeyUp]

**Visual mode** event in the php file:

```
function my_tiny_mce_before_init( $init ) {
    $init['setup'] = "function( ed ) { ed.onKeyUp.add( function( ed, e ) { repeater( e ); }); }";
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tiny_mce_before_init' );
```

**HTML mode** event in the javascript file:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $('<div id=look-at-it></div>').insertAfter('#postbox-container-1');

    $('#content').on('keyup', function( e ) {   
        repeater( e );
    });
});


var repeater = function ( e ) {
    var targetId = e.target.id;
    var text = '';

    switch ( targetId ) {

         case 'content':
             text = jQuery('#content').val(); 
             break;

         case 'tinymce':
             if ( tinymce.activeEditor )
                 text = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
             break;
    }

    jQuery('#look-at-it').html( text );
}
```

---

Tested on:

- WordPress 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if (jQuery("#wp-text-wrap").hasClass("tmce-active")){
    text1 = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent( { format : 'html' } );
}else{
    text1 = jQuery('[name="text"]').val();
```

Where *text* is the ID of the tinymce editor

Comment: Passing the param format:html, meant I got the actual html - rather than escaped &lt;p&gt;

Answer (score 0):

This is the one that seems to work for me in every situation I tested. Regardless if we start off from text mode or in visual mode and regardless of changing the modes and adding more content after that.

```
if ( tinyMCE.editors['id-of-your-editor'] ) {
    tinyMCE.editors['id-of-your-editor'].save();
    tinyMCE.editors['id-of-your-editor'].load();
    var your_content = tinyMCE.editors['id-of-your-editor'].getContent();
} else if ( document.getElementById( 'id-of-your-editor' ) ) {
    var your_content = document.getElementById( 'id-of-your-editor' ).value;
} else {
    alert ( 'Error' );
}
```